# Can't preset the value for my datebox, how do I preset the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

My datebox looks like this in the view:

```
 <div>
        <label for="Date">Date</label>
        <input asp-for=Date  value="@DateTime.Now" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" class="form-control" />
        
 </div>
```

I tried to replace `"Datetime.now"` with for example:`"16-04-2022"` and with `"@Datetime.now.ToString()"`. But I still didn't work.
This is what it would look like everytime:[image: Htmllook]

Comment: Can you not preset the date on your view model?

Answer (score 0):

Since, the Input Tag Helper sets the HTML type attribute based on the `.NET` type. To format the datetime data type, we should set the `type` attribute to `text` or `datetime`, otherwise, it will use the `type="datetime-local"`.

```
<input asp-for=Date type="text" value="@DateTime.Now" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" class="form-control" />
```

But only `type="datetime-local"` will display date and time selector, if you want to display the default datetime meanwhile can choose the datetime, I suggest you can use Bootstrap or Jquery UI etc. datetimepicker plugin.